# Initialize Map in TypeScript with dynamic values

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to initialize the `ReadOnlyMap` with values generated during runtime in TypeScript? The `Map` can be initialized if the array is provided as part of constructing the `Map`, but fails if the array is passed to it by means of a variable. Please see the code below.

```
// Works.
let X: ReadonlyMap<number, number> = new Map([
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
]);

let Y = [
    [0, 0],
    [1, 1],
];

// Does not work.
// Argument of type 'number[][]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReadonlyArray<[number, number]>'.
// Type 'number[]' is missing the following properties from type '[number, number]': 0, 1
let Z: ReadonlyMap<number, number> = new Map(Y);
```

Is there another way available to construct the `Map` in a single statement? I will like to avoid newing up an empty `Map`, call `set()` for each value and then copying its reference to `ReadonlyMap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried explicit typing of your input array? For example:

```
const Y: ReadonlyArray<[number, number]> = [
  [0, 0],
  [1, 1],
];


const Z: ReadonlyMap<number, number> = new Map<number, number>(Y);
```

Comment: Thanks. So in my question, TypeScript assigned the default type of `Y` as `number[][]` which does not convey that every inner-array element will have minimum two elements. Stating the type of `Y` explicitly assert that restriction. Now, we cannot append, say an empty inner array to Y later in the code. That gives the required guarantee to the compiler to stop complaining.